# MessageBox.Show on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, messagebox

I really don't have any idea why `Message.Box.Show` doesn't work properly.
I have necessary directive like `using System.Windows.Forms.

```
private void circle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    choose r1 = new choose();

    int x = int.Parse(beginx.Text);
    int y = int.Parse(beginy.Text);
    int w = int.Parse(wid.Text);
    int h = int.Parse(hei.Text);

    if (!((x > canvas.ActualWidth) && (y > canvas.ActualHeight) && (x > canvas.ActualWidth) && h > (canvas.ActualHeight)))
    {
        r1.rectangle(x, y, w, h, canvas);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working properly". What are you expecting to happen? What is happening or not happening instead? "Does not work" has never been a usefull post on any programming Forum :)

Comment: Sorry, I have red underline below Message.Box.Show.
Error list show that  'MessageBox" is "ambiguous reference between System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox 's element and System.Windows.MessageBox 's element "

Answer (score 4):

WPF has `System.Windows.MessageBox` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` (WinForms analogue). Both have quite similar API.
You can read more about this in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> Sorry, I have red underline below Message.Box.Show. Error list show that 'MessageBox" is "ambiguous reference between System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox 's element and System.Windows.MessageBox 's element

Remove the using directive for `System.Windows.Forms` at the top of the code file:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

...or use the fully qualified type name in your code:

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error");
```

Comment: That. The namespaces you are using include Multiple "MessageBox" classes. And as such wich one you mean is ambigious. This problem is especially commong with the Timer Class, of wich we have 3.
You need to either: Live without one of the Namespaces (in this case you propably do not need it) or use Fully Qualified typenames on all calls for Message Box (consider using a type alias).